# Django: values_list(flat=True) but for multiple fields

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model, `TestModel`

As far as I know, if I were to implement

`TestModel.objects.values_list('FieldA', flat=True)`

This results in
`[A,B,C,(...)]` (a list)

And doing this `TestModel.objects.values_list('FieldA','FieldB')`

results in `[(A,1),(B,2),(C,3),(...)]` (a list of querysets)

But is it possible to get a similar result to `Flat=True` but for multiple fields? So, if I were to use something like

`testQS = TestModel.objects.values_list('FieldA','FieldB')`

and call `testQS['FieldA']`, this will return `[A,B,C,(...)]`

Likewise, calling `testQS['FieldB']` will return `[1,2,3,(...)]`

Basically, I want to get all the data from a certain field in a `values_list` with *multiple* fields without resorting to `for loop` 
or creating `values_list` multiple times for each field.

Comment: You can't call `values_list()` with `falt=True` for multiple fields.

Comment: Yes I know that. I dont think you understood the question properly. I did not mention nor imply anywhere anywhere that I used ```flat=True``` in a ```values_list``` with multiple fields; I know this is wrong. What I want to know, and I restate, is that is it possible to get a *similar* result with ```flat=True```, using multiple fields.

Answer (score 4):

You can use itertools chain approach. It will flatten your list.

```py
import itertools

qs = TestModel.objects.values_list('FieldA','FieldB')
qs = list(itertools.chain(*qs))
return qs
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach:

```
fields = ['FieldA','FieldB']
testQS = list(TestModel.objects.values_list(*fields))
result = {field:[] for field in fields}
counter = 0
for item in testQS:
    result = {field:[*result[field],item[counter]] for field in fields}
    counter +=1
```

Comment: The key idea I'm looking for is to do it *without* the ```for``` loop though....

Answer (score 1):

You can use TestModel.objects.values_list('FieldA','FieldB', named=True)